# Display port monitor low resolution after ubuntu 18.04 updates

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I'm using a laptop with a broken disconnected internal screen. The laptop is now used as a desktop with one monitor connected via HDMI and the second monitor with a displayport connector via VGA.

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
GPU: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]

Before everything was working well, with: 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Nvidia-driver: nvidia-driver-390

Today when I booted the monitor via HDMI was no longer working. Then I tried:

```
 sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

After reboot the systeem froze after the login screen.

Via ctrl-alt-f2 I could remove the nvidia drivers and install the newer 
nvidia-driver-415

After this the booting worked normal again and both screens are working.

However the displayport/VGA screen is only in 640x480 resolution and when I try to open the settings it automatically shutsdown again.
When I open settings via i.e. sound it does work but when I click the devices tab it closes.

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Showed that it still used driver 390 so I backed this up and ran sudo nvidia-xconfig again and rebooted. After this it shows the correct version but no difference in the bugs. I also tried re-installing gnome-control-center but this also had no effect.

This was the output of my history.log this morning:

```
Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:41
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:42

Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:45
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-58.64, 4.15.0-60.67)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:47

Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: systemd-sysv:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:53

Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:24:56
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: udev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28), libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:25:12

Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:25:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.25, 237-3ubuntu10.28)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:25:22

Start-Date: 2019-09-04  11:25:24
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-5.0.0-27:amd64 (5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.0.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.0.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-27.28~18.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.0.0.25.82, 5.0.0.27.84), linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.0.0.25.82, 5.0.0.27.84), linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.0.0.25.82, 5.0.0.27.84)
End-Date: 2019-09-04  11:27:02

Start-Date: 2019-09-05  11:28:39
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.0.0-23:amd64 (5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1), linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2019-09-05  11:28:41

Start-Date: 2019-09-05  11:28:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-23-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2019-09-05  11:28:47

Start-Date: 2019-09-05  11:28:53
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (68.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 69.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2019-09-05  11:29:00

Start-Date: 2019-09-05  11:29:04
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (68.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 69.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2019-09-05  11:29:04

Start-Date: 2019-09-05  11:36:26
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.128'
Upgrade: fdisk:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libisccfg160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), uuid-runtime:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libfdisk1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libmount1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), snapd:amd64 (2.39.2+18.04, 2.40+18.04), libirs160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), libarchive13:amd64 (3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.3, 3.2.2-3.1ubuntu0.4), dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), util-linux:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libisc169:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), xkb-data:amd64 (2.23.1-1ubuntu1, 2.23.1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1), mount:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libblkid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libisc-export169:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 (1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.0, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.0), libuuid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), liblwres160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), rfkill:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libdns-export1100:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), bsdutils:amd64 (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.3, 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4), libisccc160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.0, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.0), libbind9-160:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), libdns1100:amd64 (1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.8, 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.9), docker-ce:amd64 (5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic, 5:19.03.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic, 5:19.03.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
Remove: linux-modules-5.0.0-23-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2019-09-05  11:37:00
```

This is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected primary 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   640x480       59.94* 
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+640+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.90  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

when running gnome-control-center the output is:

```
(gnome-control-center:5176): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 16:09:48.333: Couldn't find a mode to activate monitor at DP-1

(gnome-control-center:5176): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:09:48.341: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:5176): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:09:48.341: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:5176): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:09:48.341: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:5176): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:09:48.341: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:5176): GLib-ERROR **: 16:09:48.341: g_variant_new: expected GVariant of type '*' but received value has type '(null)'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

If I run sudo gnome-control-center it does open the devices panel but it is empty.
I tried searching for these errors but without any luck.

The output of xorg.conf is:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 415.27


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And lscpi | grep -i vga/nvidia show:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
and
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

and ps aux | grep xsettings

```
gdm       1445  0.0  0.3 638912 30028 tty1     Sl+  15:41   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
user111    2445  0.0  0.2 494732 21924 tty2     Sl+  15:41   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
user111    5675  0.0  0.0  21536  1008 pts/0    S+   16:18   0:00 grep --color=auto xsettings
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

EDIT:

I found another HDMI cable and decided to connect that instead of a VGA cable (the displayport connector has VGA/HDMI/DVI). With HDMI everything works normally.

This is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   ''   ''        ''      ''
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   ''    ''       ''      ''
```

So althought this workaround works for me. Their is still something wrong somewhere.

While looking for answers I saw a lot more questions of people with the same issue so let's see if we can find a good solution.

So combining xrandr and gnome-control-center we get:

DP -> VGA : DP-1 connected primary 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm

DP -> HMDI : HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm

So it seems when connecting via VGA the system doesn't switch from DP to VGA (which I'm guessing should be the case, also because gnome-control-center outputs: Couldn't find a mode to activate monitor at DP-1).

Or the actual displayport connect hardware is broken (however I cannot check this, but it seems not likely for it to break during the night).

So if the issue is that DP doesn't switch to VGA, which driver would be responsible for this?

Comment: What happens if you unplug the DP-0 monitor, then launch settings, then plug the DP-0 monitor back in?

Comment: @Wyck If I unplug the display port everything works normally, because the hdmi works fine and in good resolution. Gnome-control-center also works fine then. From the output from lscpi it looks like the displayport is running on the integrated gpu and not on the nvidia.

Comment: @Wyck sorry misread your question, if I plug the monitor back in the settings closes automatically and the monitor starts in 640.