# Wrong resolution (missing 1920x1080) on Lenovo w520 after update to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, display, lenovo, display-resolution

Apologies if the question is already answered; I poked around but don't know enough to figure out what to do.

I am using a w520 and recently updated from 14.04 to 18.04 (with a broken 16.04 in the middle where the UI completely stopped working--low graphics mode-- and had to be rescued.)

I now have a gui back, but the resolution is 1600x900 rather than the expected 1920x1080.

On bios, display mode is set to discrete and optimus is off.

I tried manually installing nvidia-driver-390 (don't know if that was the correct one, but it seemed to be what other w520s installed) -- also

ubuntu-drivers devices shows:

```
 ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DFAsv000017AAsd000021CFbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

xrandr shows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1600x900      60.22*+  50.01  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
sudo get-edid|parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
1 potential busses found: 2
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 2
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "�p"
    ModelName "�p"
    VendorName "LEN"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 1 of 2008
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 340 190
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 106.00 1600 1664 1706 1930 900 903 906 912 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 106.00 1600 1664 1706 2324 900 903 906 912 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

Ran sudo nvidia-xconfig,

/etc/X11/xorg.conf became:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.116  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Sun Jan 27 07:47:55 PST 2019


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

sudo lspci | grep -i vga/nvidia

is empty.

sudo modprobe -v nvidia (from [Display port monitor low resolution after ubuntu 18.04 updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171077/display-port-monitor-low-resolution-after-ubuntu-18-04-updates))

runs without error.

On Software&Updates=>Additional Drivers, shows:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obrZt.png)

Can anyone help me? I'd love to know not just what to do but what is going on and how the fix works.
Thanks!

===Update: tried following https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/ including suggested ppa, to no avail.

===Update: Tried changing to 340 via the gui, which caused it to instead go to noveau, become corrupted, and be 480x480. After purging etc, I think I'm back to previous state.

Output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display':

```
 '
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Lenovo MMC/SD Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
0e:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done. Not sure what I should learn from this, though... is the important part that nvidia kernel driver is in use? (edited due to <enter> too soon)

Comment: I have a machine like yours and run with Optimus and the enable switch (just below "Optimus") on. The Nvidia 390.116 works just fine.  A couple of reboots may be necessary to get the card reset after making these changes.

Comment: Yikes, not only has nothing seemed to work, but I think adding the ppa from https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/  has totally wrecked my computer. Software&Updates now says I'm using an alternate driver (from nvidia-driver-390). I can't figure out how to go back to whatever was there-- removing the ppa leaves everything in a broken state. And now wifi is broken too.

Comment: Hm, I re-enabled Optimus and now I can't get a GUI. Also still can't get back to the proprietary nvidia drivers. Wifi appears broken (wasn't previously) so somehow I impacted that too. Am I at the point where I should just try a clean reinstall?

Comment: There a many Nvidia driver cleanup questions/answers here, but a reinstall may be the easiest approach.  No ppa needed to get the working 390 driver. One "nomodeset" on the kernel line first boot with the default nouveau driver until you install the Nvidia 390. No wireless issues at all.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "one 'nomodeset' on the kernel line? Wireless successfully loaded on reboot so that's not an issue. For future reference, how can I actually remove a ppa (and have a working system afterwards)? When I tried --remove, it left things in a broken state (unable to reach proprietary drivers). Disappointing if such mistakes can't be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Use *cvt* and *xrandr* commands to add 1920x1080 as below

```
xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | sed 's/^.*MHz//' | sed 's/\/.*//' | sed 's/^.*Modeline//' | sed 's/\"//g')
sudo xrandr --addmode $(sudo xrandr -q | grep " connected" | cut -d " " -f 1) $(echo $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | sed 's/^.*MHz//' | sed 's/\/.*//' | sed 's/^.*Modeline//' | sed 's/\"//g') | sed 's/\ .*//')
xrandr -s $(echo $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | sed 's/^.*MHz//' | sed 's/\/.*//' | sed 's/^.*Modeline//' | sed 's/\"//g') | sed 's/\ .*//')
```

or use simple bash script from github [github.com/porczynski/add-display-resolution](https://github.com/porczynski/add-display-resolution)

```
wget https://github.com/porczynski/add-display-resolution/archive/master.zip
unzip ./master.zip
cd add-display-resolution
```

Works for me.
You can add any resolution by simple command, eg.:

```
./addre 1080
```